# Cuando se dejo de usar los comandos mysql_comando y en que version de php?

Tags: php, mysqli

Me gustaría saber cuándo (año) se dejaron de usar los comandos con `mysql_<comando>` y en qué versión de PHP,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como se indica en la pagina de PHP, [Aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

> Warning
>
> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> mysqli_connect()
>
> PDO::__construct()

#### Traduccion

> Advertencia
>
> Esta extensión fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0. En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones MySQLi o PDO_MySQL. Véase también la guía MySQL: elegir una API y sus P+F relacionadas para más información. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> mysqli_connect()
>
> PDO::__construct()

Hasta la version **5.5.0** se dejaron obsoletas las funciones `mysql_`

**PHP 5.5.0** fue lanzado el *20 de Junio de 2013*

Nota de lanzamiento: [Aqui](https://evertpot.com/php-55-released/)

> June 20, 2013
>   PHP 5.5.0 released!
>
> PHP 5.5 has been released! Quite exciting stuff, and pretty great to see the pace of new releases. Props to the dev team!