# limitar registros diarios

Tags: php, mysql

he editado este post para ver si me logro entender bien 
estoy tratando de hacer un insert de manera que solo permita ingresar 3 registros por fecha, me explico 2017-02-12, a esta fecha solo puede haber tres registros, para un nuevo registro debería intentar con otro día o mejor dicho con otra fecha, si ya hay tres registro con una misma fecha y se trata de hacer otro registro con esa misma fecha ya registrada debería mandar en mensaje: 
 ('Se ha superado el limite de registros diarios, intente con otra Fecha!') actualmente tengo esto, pero el error que me da es que solo manda el mensaje que ('Se ha superado el limite de registros diarios, intente con otra Fecha!')
y no registra

```
   <?php 
    include("conexion.php");

    if (isset ($_POST['guardar'])){ 
        $cedula=$_REQUEST['cedula'];
        $idtipodecita=$_REQUEST['idtipodecita'];
        $fecha_cita=$_REQUEST['fecha_cita'];
        $estado=$_REQUEST['estado'];
        $telefono=$_REQUEST['telefono'];

        $cita_x_dia = 2;
        $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cita_previa WHERE fecha_cita='$fecha_cita'";
        $res=mysql_query($sql,$link) or die ( mysql_error());
        $nrows=mysql_num_rows($res);
        if($res <= $cita_x_dia) 
        {
            if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO cita_previa (cedula,idtipodecita,fecha_cita,estado,telefono) VALUES 
('$cedula','$idtipodecita','$fecha_cita','$estado','$telefono')",$link)){

                echo "<script>alert ('Cita Previa registrada, pronto lo contactaremos!');</script>
<META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT=0;URL=http:citaprevia.php>";
            }else{
                echo "<script>alert ('Se ha superado el limite de registros diarios, intente con otra Fecha!');</script>
<META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT=0;URL=http:citaprevia.php>";
     }


?>
```

por fin lo he solucionado quedando de esta manera anexo el cod para quien le pueda servir gracias a un amigo... con esto doy el tema por cerrado

```
<?php 
include("conexion.php");

if (isset ($_POST['guardar'])){ 
    $cedula=$_REQUEST['cedula'];
    $idtipodecita=$_REQUEST['idtipodecita'];
    $fecha_cita=$_REQUEST['fecha_cita'];
    $estado=$_REQUEST['estado'];
    $telefono=$_REQUEST['telefono'];



    $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Registros' FROM cita_previa WHERE fecha_cita='$fecha_cita'";
    $res=mysql_query($sql,$link) or die ( mysql_error());
    $nrows=mysql_num_rows($res);
    list( $no_registros ) = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    if( $no_registros >= 2 ) {

        echo "<script>alert ('Se ha superado el limite de registros diarios, intente con otra Fecha!');</script><META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT=0;URL=http:citaprevia.php>";

        die (' ');
    }else{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO cita_previa (cedula,idtipodecita,fecha_cita,estado,telefono) VALUES('$cedula','$idtipodecita','$fecha_cita','$estado','$telefono')",$link);

    echo "<script>alert ('Cita Previa registrada, pronto lo contactaremos!');</script><META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT=0;URL=http:citaprevia.php>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solución fue:

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Registros' FROM cita_previa WHERE 
fecha_cita='$fecha_cita'";
$res=mysql_query($sql,$link) or die ( mysql_error());
$nrows=mysql_num_rows($res);
list( $no_registros ) = mysql_fetch_array($res);
if( $no_registros >= 2 ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza la función count() para saber el numero de lineas de la lista.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM cita_previa WHERE fecha_cita='$fecha_cita'";

$res=mysql_query($sql,$link);
#$nrows=mysql_num_rows($res);
if(count($res)<=15){ # utiliza count()
```

por otro lado las funciones mysql_* estan OBSOLETAS utiliza un objeto PDO
suerte!

EDITADO

te dejo un ejemplo con un objeto PDO, una función de consulta y el uso de COUNT() fuera de la consulta.

PDO dbcore.php [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047264/use-of-pdo-in-classes)
Advertencia ! puede contener errores de tabulado si copias lo siguiente

```
<?php
Config::write('db.host', 'localhost');
Config::write('db.port', '3306');
Config::write('db.basename', 'puravida');
Config::write('db.user', 'root');
Config::write('db.password', '');

class Config {

    static $confArray; 

    public static function read($name) {
        return self::$confArray[$name];
    }

    public static function write($name, $value) {
        self::$confArray[$name] = $value;
    }
}

class Core {
    public $dbh; // manejador de conexion de la base de datos.
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct()  {

        $conexion = 'mysql:host=' . Config::read('db.host') . ';dbname=' . Config::read('db.basename') .';charset=utf8'. ';port=' . Config::read('db.port') .';connect_timeout=15';
        $user = Config::read('db.user');
        $password = Config::read('db.password');
        $this->dbh = new PDO($conexion, $user, $password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
        $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);// desactivar emulación de querys peparadors
        $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);// lanzar excepciones.
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            $object = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $object;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
<?php
```

FUNCIÓN agenda.php
Advertencia ! puede contener errores de tabulado si copias lo siguiente

```
    public static function Ver($idpaciente, $idpersonal)
    {
    if (!isset($idpaciente)) {
       $idpaciente=0;
    }
    if (!isset($idpersonal)) {
        $idpersonal=0;
    }

    // section 10-0-0-5-4286bd1e:14f806bdbcd:-8000:0000000000000C73 begin
    $qury='select DISTINCT
    agenda.idagenda as id,
    agenda.horainicio AS hora,
    agenda.horafinal AS hasta,
    salas.sala 
    FROM
    agenda
    INNER JOIN salasagenda ON salasagenda.idagenda = agenda.idagenda
    INNER JOIN salas ON salas.idsala = salasagenda.idsala
    INNER JOIN personal ON personal.idpersonal = agenda.idpersonal
    INNER JOIN pacientes ON pacientes.idpaciente = agenda.idpaciente
    INNER JOIN personas ON personas.ci = pacientes.ci
    INNER JOIN roles ON roles.idrol = pacientes.idrol
    WHERE
    (agenda.FechaFinal >='.date('Y-m-d').') AND (
    agenda.horainicio BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL "4" HOUR) and TIME("21:00:00")) and (agenda.idpaciente='.$idpaciente.' OR agenda.idpersonal='.$idpersonal.') ORDER BY agenda.horainicio';
    try {
    $bd=Core::getInstance();
    $qbdobj=$bd->dbh->prepare($qury);
    if ($qbdobj->execute()) {
        $qbdobj->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         return $qbdobj->fetchall();
         //print_r($qbdobj);
    }else{
        //print_r($qbdobj);
    }
```

USANDO COUNT() miagenda.php. 
Advertencia ! puede contener errores de tabulado si copias lo siguiente

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/Clases/class.Agenda.php';
$agenda=Clases_Agenda::Ver($idpaciente,$idpersonal);
?>
<div class="agenda">
<section>
    <h3>Hola <?php echo $nombre."! "; ?>para hoy <b><?php
    echo date('Y-m-d');  ?></b> tiene <b><?php echo count($agenda); ?></b> recordatorio(s);</h3><br>
    <?php 
    //print_r($idpaciente);
    //print_r($idpersonal);
    //$agenda= new Clases_Agenda();
    //print_r($agenda);
    if (!is_array($agenda)) {
        echo "No tienes nada para hoy.";
    }else{
         echo "<table border=1 width=100%><tr>";
         echo "<th>Desde hora</th>";
         echo "<th>Hasta hora</th>";
         echo "<th>Sala</th><th>acciones</th></tr>";
         for ($i=0; $i <count($agenda) ; $i++) {    
                echo"<tr><td>".$agenda[$i]['hora']."</td><td>".$agenda[$i]['hasta']."</td><td>".$agenda[$i]['sala']."</td>";
                //echo"<tr><td>".$agenda[$i]['hasta']."</td>";
                echo '<td><a href="agenda.php?url=modificar&id='.$agenda[$i]['id'].'">modificar</a></td>';
        }                       
             echo"</tr>";
         }
         echo"</table>";
         echo"<p></p>";

     ?>
     </section>
     </div>
```

También si fíjate que estoy comprobando que $agenda sea un array.

```
if (!is_array($agenda))
```

suerte!

Comment: no me funciona,,

Comment: lo he corregido así pro igual no me funciona

`$fecha_cita = date("j F, Y");`
`$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Registros' FROM cita_previa WHERE fecha_cita='$fecha_cita'";`
`$res=mysql_query($sql,$link) or die ( mysql_error());`
`list( $no_registros )=mysql_fetch_array($res);`
`if(count($no_registros) <=2)`

Comment: exactamente que error te da?, haz pruebas imprimiendo los resultados.
me parece que COUNT(*) esta mal.
deberia ser:
    $sql = "select * AS 'Registros' FROM cita_previa WHERE fecha_cita='$fecha_cita'";
    $res=mysql_query($sql,$link)
    print(res) #prueba que los resultados sean lo que quieres.
    print(count($res)).

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, mi respuesta, similar a las anteriores, además me sumo a que puedas ocupar las funciones de mysqli en vez de las de mysql, te dejo este enlace: [Cuando se dejo de usar los comandos mysql_comando y en que version de php?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48978/cuando-se-dejo-de-usar-los-comandos-mysql-comando-y-en-que-version-de-php)

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM cita_previa WHERE fecha_cita='$fecha_cita'";

$res=mysql_query($sql,$link);
#$nrows=mysql_num_rows($res);
if(count($res)<15){ # utiliza count()
```

Vi que en todos los ejemplos (respuestas), incluso en tu pregunta dice `$res <= 15` en estricto rigor si quieres que el maximo sea 15 deberia ser asi `$res < 15` o en el caso de este ejemplo `count($res) < 15`
Si no, cuando llegue al 15 ingresará un registro más.

Espero te sirva.

---

Esto es para responder la duda, y dar como ejemplo según la conversación de esta respuesa.

Suponiendo que tienes una tabla `cita_previa` y esta tiene 15 registros donde en el campo `fecha_cita`, de todos los registros tiene el valor de `2010-10-10`. Entonces existe un limite diario de registros, donde el limite es 15 registros, osea en este ejemplo ya no se debería admitir mas registros para la fecha `2010-10-10`.

Entonces en la pagina de PHP que ingresa registros tendremos.

```
<?php 

// donde $_POST['fecha'], viene de un formulario enviado por POST y el valor de este es `2010-10-10`
$fecha_cita = isset($_POST['fecha']) ? $_POST['fecha']: '';

// Comprobamos que ya no hayan mas de 15 registros con esa fecha.
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE fecha = '$fecha_cita'", $link)
// Basicamente la consulta dice `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE fecha = '2010-10-10'`
// comparamos la cantidad con el numero que le pusimos de limite
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) < 15){ 
// si habiamos dicho que teniamos 15 registros con esa fecha, estara preguntando si 15 < 15, como no lo es, irá al else.
// si es menor, ingresará uno nuevo
} else {
// si es 15 o mayor a 15 no ingresará un nuevo registro.
}
```

Espero pueda funcionar.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53527/discussion-on-answer-by-jolsalazar-limitar-registros-diarios).

Answer (score 1):

No te aconsejo que sigas utilizando `MySQL*`, son inseguros contra ataques de [inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php).

> **ADVERTENCIA:** [MySQL*](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php) fue declarada obsoleta en `PHP 5.5.0` y eliminada en `PHP 7.0.0.` En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones `MySQLi` o `PDO_MySQL`.

**Veamos un ejemplo MySQLi:**

```
//Fecha obtenido desde tu formulario.
$fecha_cita = $_REQUEST['fecha_cita'];

//Sentencia.
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT cedula FROM cita_previa WHERE fecha_cita='$fecha_cita'";
//Comprobamos existencia de registros en Base de datos y mientras sea inferior a total de (3) registros, insertamos un registro nuevo.
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) < 3) {
    //Insertamos registro nuevo a la Base de datos.
} else {
   echo 'Tu registro no se inserto, la Base de datos ya cumple con los regisrtos permitidos.';
}
```

Te aconsejo utilizar sentencias [prepare()](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php), para asi lograr mayor seguridad en tu aplicación web.

**Ejemplo mysqli_prepare():**

```
//Fecha obtenido desde tu formulario.
$fecha_cita = $_REQUEST['fecha_cita'] ?: '';

//Sentencia (SELECT).
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT cedula FROM cita_previa WHERE fecha_cita = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$fecha_cita);//Ligamos parametros marcadores, es decir los valores ?.
$stmt->execute();//Ejecutamos sentencia.
//Comprobamos registros.
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows < 3) {

   $stmt->close();//Cerramos sentencia.

   //Sentencia (INSERT).
   $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO cita_previa (cedula,idtipodecita,fecha_cita,estado,telefono) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
   $stmt->bind_param("iisss",$cedula,$idtipodecita,$fecha_cita,$estado,$telefono); //Atención, iisss,  son los tipos para el correspondiente enlazado de variable, deben de coincidir.

   //i     la variable correspondiente es de tipo entero
   //d     la variable correspondiente es de tipo double
   //s     la variable correspondiente es de tipo string
   //b     la variable correspondiente es un blob y se envía en paquetes

   $stmt->execute(); //Ejecutamos sentencia
   $stmt->close(); //Cerramos sentencia.
   echo 'Tu registro se inserto correctamente a la Base de Datos.';

} else {
    $stmt->close();//Cerramos sentencia.
   echo 'Tu registro no se inserto, la Base de datos ya cumple con los regisrtos permitidos.';
}
```

Comment: gracias amigo,actualmente uso PDO, lo que pasa es que ese era un codigo viejo y queria tenerlo de recuerdo y muchas gracias por poner un ejemplo en pdo ya que lo necesitaba muchas gracias

Comment: De nada amig@, espero que te pueda servir el ejemplo. Suerte con el proyecto, Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

me parece que debes hacer una consulta utilizando la funcion COUNT de mysql para que te cuente los registros que cumplan el siguiente criterio 
WHERE fecha_cita='Fecha_hoy';

si la cantida de registros es igual o mayor a 15 lanzas el mensaje que ya hay mas de 15 registros y listo

Comment: Recomendaria que esta respuesta se agregue como un comentario, o en su lugar se agrege un ejemplo de codigo, para que la respuesta sea entendible a la comunidad

Comment: podrías darme un ejemplo