# SQL: COUNT y AVG según resultado de consulta con Foreing Key

Tags: sql

Encontré unos ejercicios en Internet de consulta SQL, pero me quedé trabado en uno, esperaba que pudieran ayudarme.

A partir de las siguientes tablas, me pide:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Mostrar el nombre de los partidos, cantidad de votos y promedio de edad de los votantes masculinos que eligieron gobernador agrupar por nombre del partido y ordenar por cantidad de votos descendente*

Básicamente, entiendo que tendría que poner un `COUNT` y un `AVG`. Lo que no entiendo, es como hacer para que solo me cuente los que cumplan la condición indicada (masulinos y votantes a agrupar).

¿Me podrian ayudar?

Comment: Hola Facundo, ¿en qué manejador de base de datos te encuentras trabajando tu solución? En la medida de lo posible edita tu pregunta poniendo la estructura de las tablas y la inserción de algunos datos, esto dará pauta a que más personas intenten ayudarte con tu problema.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Es una pregunta teórica. Eso es todo lo que tengo, no es práctico sino teórico. No tengo tablas armadas, solo lo que otorga el ejercicio. En MySQL sería la sintaxis.

Comment: Dado que es una pregunta teórica, ¿solo esperarías una explicación del funcionamiento? es decir, ¿no quieres código?

Comment: No, el ejercicio pide la consulta SQL, a partir de las tablas indicadas ahí. No tengo una tabla armada, solo lo que muestra. Pero el ejercicio pide la consulta. Sin embargo, lo que quiero es entenderlo. Para poder realizar consultas similares en el futuro.

Comment: Con la información proporcionada sería muy difícil darte una respuesta, dado que [es.so] es una sitio de preguntas y respuestas puntuales, y entre más detalles en la pregunta es mejor. Algo muy valioso en las preguntas son los intentos que han tenido por resolver el problema que se pregunta, aunque el código no funcione se valora mucho el esfuerzo por parte del usuario que postea una pregunta.

Comment: No puedo ayudar con eso, por que no tengo codigo que haya ejecutado. Solo escrito y pensado la respuesta que me daría al realizar dicha consulta. Y la verdad estoy estancado, no se como hacer para que me devuelva un count a partir de cierta condicion. (hasta donde se, no se puede poner un select como argumento del count). Es decir:

SELECT count(select * where sexo=M AND...)...

Comment: Ah pero con el código que hayas escrito lo puedes poner en tu pregunta, aunque no corra (eso es lo de menos), eso te dará algunas ventajas: **1)** Otras personas encontrarán los detalles y te podrán ayudar de manera más puntual. **2)** Otras personas podrán hacer observaciones si la forma en que estás codificando es la más óptima. **3)** Recibirás recomendaciones, incluso referencias a la documentación oficial etc. Esto hará que tu pregunta sea más relevante y podrás ganar más reputación por preguntas de gran calidad :)

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el enlace donde podemos encontrar esos ejercicios de SQL? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

ya que no tengo puntos para comentar!. 
Deberías dar información sobre el problema que tienes en tu código o consulta y los errores que te da. no podemos hacer todo el ejercicio para que lo copies.

para la utilización de COUNT() revisa esta discusión sobre el uso de count [limitar registros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48992/limitar-registros-diarios)

```
"select nombre.partidos,
count(cargo.partidos_electores) as votos,
avg(edad.electores) from pratidos, electores, partidos_electores
where codigo_partido.partidos = $idpartido and"....
```